# Connection from android studio to php to mysql stored in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, android, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create a login part of an app which will save the name, user_name and user_pass in a MySQL database stored in phpmyadmin.

I have looked up a lot of answers in stackoverflow and have followed YouTube tutorials which have worked and inserted data directly from php to MySQL.  However, when I have tried to input the data from android studio emulator, the PK id field in the db is increasing by 1 but the string values are not transferring therefore these fields are left black in the database.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String reg_url = "http://10.0.2.2/webapp/register.php";
    String login_url = "http://10.0.2.2/webapp/login.php";
    String method = params[0];
    if (method.equals("register")) {
        String name = params[1];
        String user_name = params[2];
        String user_pass = params[3];
        try {
            URL url = new URL(reg_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            //httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("user_pass", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_pass, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            OS.close();
            InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            IS.close();
            //httpURLConnection.connect();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return "Registration Success...";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

}

in another class Register I have

```
   public void userReg(View view){
    name=ET_NAME.getText().toString();
    user_name=ET_USER_NAME.getText().toString();
    user_pass=ET_USER_PASS.getText().toString();
    String method="register";
    BackgroundTask backgroundTask=new BackgroundTask(this);
    backgroundTask.execute(method,name,user_name,user_pass);
    finish();
   }
```

my connection to the db is shown below :

```
<?php  
    $db_name = "gohereshopping";  
    $mysql_user = "root";  
    $mysql_pass = "root";  
    $server_name = "localhost";  
    $con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name);  
?>
```

and I insert as shown below:

```
<?php  
    require "init.php";  
    $name = $_POST["user"];  
    $user_name = $_POST["user_name"];  
    $user_pass = $_POST["user_pass"];  
    $sql_query = "insert into user_info values('$name','$user_name','$user_pass');";  
?>
```

would this be rectified by adding an array and using a FOREACH loop? or through use of JSON

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience in php but I made something like it so I think you should write your columns names like

```
$sql_query = "insert into user_info ( name, user_name, user_pass ) values('$name','$user_name','$user_pass')";
// where name, user_name, user_pass are your columns names in the table
```

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$sql_query = "insert into user_info values(null,'$name','$user_name','$user_pass');";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not able to call variables inside queries.

try this

$sql_query = "insert into user_info values('".$name."','".$user_name."','".$user_pass."');";